# SSRS with analysis services, how do I filter a group?

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssas

Using report builder 3.0, I have a report that queries a cube.  How do I use the group filter in SSRS to further filter my mdx results (I can't do the filtering in the mdx itself). Obvious with SQL, but not so obvious with MDX!

Darren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter data set and groups in SSRS report filter after result obtained from MDX.
Double click on data set or group and on filter tab you can give filter expression.

**SYNTAX:**

```
Expression: =Fields!col1.Value
Operator: =, >, <, <>, Like, IN, BETWEEN, Top N, Bottom N, Top %, Bottom %
Value: =

Expression: Fields!col1.Value  Operator:  > Value: =10
```

Above expression will filter out col1 value > 10

Comment: Thanks, I realise that, but I am not sure of the syntax for filters when the dataset is based on mdx? Can you provide an example?  Thanks

Comment: Thanks for that Yogesh.  I was assuming that because it was an MDX dataset, the syntax would be different, but of course the realisation dawns that we are just dealing with data at this point so the filter is the same regardless of the datasource.  I needed to filter on the 'value' of a member which was not being returned in the dataset and thought I could use MDX syntax in the filter to refer to that value, instead I just added the value into the original MDX so that I could filter on it.